# 3 DIV in one row

Tags: html, css

I need three `<div>` elements in one row.

Example:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="left">
         <!-- width 100% , float:left  -->
    </div>

    <div class="center">
         <!-- width 960px , margin:0 auto  -->

         <div class="sidebar">
              <!-- width 350px , float:right  -->
         </div>

    </div>

    <div class="right">
         <!-- width 100% , float:right  -->
    </div>

</div>
```

Example image:
[image]

I want to set the same background for `div.right` as `div.sidebar`.

Comment: Could you explain why you're trying to do this? I don't see the purpose from the image

Comment: set all their floats to left. Also, make sure their width is less than or equal to the wrapping div

Comment: Why are you semantically separating 2 elements that according to their rendering are joined?

Comment: are you trying to do a paralax or sprite design? what is it do you want to do?

Comment: what's inside left and right divs? are those divs empty? you only want them to extend the background?

Comment: Put `.right` inside `.center` and apply the background to `.center`?

Comment: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2dkn5z5.jpg
Do know you any other solution for implementing it?

Comment: arieljuod: Yes, They are empty. I need repeat the background if screen resolution is more than 960px.
-
-
Niels Keurentjes: Because I don't know how to do it. Sidebar must have the same background as the div.right ...but div.right is empty, with 100% width. If screen respolution is more than 960px (wrapper width) - background must repeat to right. Do you understand me? Sorry, my ingslsh is very bad, but on the picture, you can see it, i think so.

Comment: tell me if mine is what you were looking for.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a CSS3 `calc()` approach, which has better browser support. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Imposiible to do with consistent result with div. Use table.

Answer (score 3):

css file

```
 .main{ background-color: #ddd;}
.left {

    display: table-cell;
}
.middle {

    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
.right {

    display: table-cell;
}
```

html code

```
<div class="main">
<div class="left"> Some content </div>
<div class="middle"> This should fill the space left </div>
<div class="right"> Some other content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline style on displaying the divs :

```
style="display:inline"

<div class="row">

<div style="display:inline" class="left">
     <!-- width 100% , float:left  -->
</div>

<div style="display:inline" class="center">
     <!-- width 960px , margin:0 auto  -->

     <div style="display:inline" `class="sidebar">
          <!-- width 350px , float:right  -->
     </div>

  </div>

  <div class="right">
     <!-- width 100% , float:right  -->
  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 - CSS Calc

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLthb/3/)**. This solution uses the `calc()` CSS3 function. [This is supported by all major browsers, notably going back to IE9](http://caniuse.com/calc).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="cf">
    <div id="left" class="side"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right" class="side"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container div {
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}
#center {
    width:960px;
    background:#FFFF00;
}
.side {
    width:calc(50% - 480px);
    background:#FF0000;
}
```

*(Note: Because this solution requires floats I've also included the [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/))*

---

### Solution 2 - Flexbox

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLthb/)**. This technique uses the CSS3 `flexbox` model. Browser compatibility aside this is my favoured approach, but  [this isn't a good solution if you want to target legacy browsers](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" class="flex"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right" class="flex"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    display:flex;
}
#wrapper div {
    height:300px;
}
.flex {
    flex:1;
}
#center {
    width:960px;
}
```

Comment: That's what I need, but this solution not supported by the last version of popular web browsers? Do you know other solution to do this?

Comment: Nothing else really sprang to mind other than using JavaScript to reposition the left and right DIVs. That was why I asked you what the purpose of this was. I'm also not sure what you mean by "but this solution not supported by the last version of popular web browsers". It **is** supported for the latest versions of **all** of the popular web browsers, just notably not IE<11 (/10 without `-ms-`)

Comment: check out my answer. I just re-arranged your divs.

Answer (score 0):

I basicly did it for you. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9AcG/)

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <style>

            #row{
            background: grey;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            float: left;
            }
            #left {
            background: #ccc;
            width: 60%;
            float: left;
            }
            #right{
            background: #999;
            width: 40%;
            float: right;

            }

            #content-left{
                width: 70%;
                float: right;
            }
            #right-top-wrapper{
            width: 100%;
            background: #666;
                color: #f3f3f3;
                float: left;
            }
            #right-top{
                width: 40%;

                clear: both;

            }
            #right-bottom{
                width: 40%;
                float: left;
                clear: both;
            }


            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="row">
            <div id="left">
                <div id="content-left">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboru
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <div id="right-top-wrapper">
                    <div id="right-top">
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="right-bottom">

                <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </body>
            <html>
```

Comment: 1) Could you please provide a fiddle to show how this works and 2) I don't see how this achieves what the OP asked for.

Comment: 1. Copy the code and paste it in notepad. 2. save it somewhere. 3. pull it up on a browser. Then you will see it is exactly what he asked.

Comment: I've added your code to JSFiddle Lesly, but it doesn't fix their issue.

Comment: I'm not going to sit here in explain each line of code. This is simple css and html.

Comment: This site is about helping people, if your code doesn't answer the question, then yes you should try to explain what you were trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

here you go **3 DIV in one row**
Click on Run code snippet to see the result

```html
<div id="d3" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">content1</div>
<div id="d3" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">content2</div>
<div id="d3" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">content3</div>
```

```
<div id="d1" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">**content1**</div>
<div id="d1" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">**content1**</div>
<div id="d3" style="display:inline-block; width:100px;">**content3**</div>
```